# How to parse array in PHP.

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the following array I want to get the element one by one.

```
"attachment":"["Apple","car","home","scooter"]"
```

Comment: Well that's not a valid construct anyway.

Comment: not valid in the sence

Comment: this is not array, your array should be like `array("attachment"=>["Apple","car","home","scooter"])`

Answer (score 2):

If the array is in JSON form you do [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and the iterate over the array

Comment: Pretty sure that's not even a valid JSON though in the original example.